# Preserve shape after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Ok so lets say I have a df that is frequency of animals in different houses:

```
   Animal  Frequency
0  Dog     5
1  Cat     7
2  Cat     2
3  Fish    2
4  Dog     8
```

Now lets say I dont care about which household, I just want the mean of each animal to be displayed under frequency, so i get the mean with:

```
mean = df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()
```

Now this gives me a series (or dataframe in my actual larger df) with the index as the different animals:

```
      Frequency
Dog     6.5
Cat     4.5
Fish    2
```

Now I just want my original df to be:

```
   Animal  Frequency
0  Dog     6.5
1  Cat     4.5
2  Cat     4.5
3  Fish    2
4  Dog     6.5
```

Tried using imbedded for loop (Remember my actual project the mean returns a dataframe not a series):

```
for idx in df.index:
    for item in mean.Animal:    
        if df.Animal[idx] == mean.Animal[item]:
            df.at[idx, 'Frequency'] = mean.at[item, 'Frequency']
```

The above code just runs indefinitely, the actual dataframe is very large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) in order to preserve the original shape after aggregating with the mean:

```
df['Frequency'] = df.groupby('Animal').transform('mean')
```

**Output**

```
   Animal  Frequency
0    Dog        6.5
1    Cat        4.5
2    Cat        4.5
3   Fish        2.0
4    Dog        6.5
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about that function I would usually remerge values back onto my original df. Thanks yatu